# mongo geoWithin query using sphere radius from the current document

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I'd like to construct a query to return users who are within a search radius which is the smaller value of my radius field and theirs. In other words, the query should return the same result for both users of any pair of users.

A user document looks like this:

```
{
  name:   "Julian",
    radius: 100,
    location: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [-79.8890232, 8.5419445],
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm thinking along these lines: Run the query with *my* search radius, then iterate through the cursor, check the difference in locations against the other user's radius, building a list of userIds:

```
const me = db.users.findOne(myUserId)
let nearByUserIds = []
db.users.find({
  _id: {$ne:myUserId},
  location: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ me.location.coordinates, me.radius] } }
  }).forEach((u) => {

    if (u.radius < me.radius && distanceBetween(u.location.coordinates, me.location.coordinates) < u.radius) {
      nearByUserIds.push(u._id)
    }
  })
```

My question: is this possible to do in one query with no forEach?