# Geospatial $near within current document field value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, geospatial, spring-mongodb

Take this query:

```
{ 'location' : { '$near' : [x,y], '$maxDistance' : this.field } }
```

I want to assign $maxDistance the value of the specified field from the current evaluated document. Is that possible?

Comment: Nope, that is not possible.

Comment: You're not the first one with this question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970436/mongo-geowithin-query-using-sphere-radius-from-the-current-document

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Then you are reading the wrong posts. It's been possible for some time. You just do it differently.

Comment: @NeilLunn: well, this exact need may be satisfied in an alternate way, but the answer to the general question ("can I use document's fields in a query?") is still a "no".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No the general answer is use `$redact` or even worse `$where`. Always has been.

Comment: @NeilLunn: the linked question, is it asking the same thing? Can we dup-close it, now that you have this answer?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'd love to, but the answer needs an upvote here to do that. It certainly answers the other question even if the OP here thinks it's not their case. I kind of think it is though because it's not uncommon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You just use [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) instead. Beware the catches and read carefully.

Presuming that your intent to is to store a field such as `"travelDistance"` to indicate on the document that any such searches must be "within" that supplied distance from the queried point to be valid. Then we simply query and evaluate the condition with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$geoNear": {
    "near": { 
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [x,y]
    },
    "spherical": true,
    "distanceField": "distance"
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": { "$lte": [ "$distance", "$travelDistance" ] },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
])
```

The only catch is that [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) just like [`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) will only return a certain number of documents "near" in the first place. You can tune that with the options, but unlike the general query form, this is basically guaranteeing that the eventual returned results will be less than the specified "nearest" numbers.

As long as you are aware of that, then this is perfectly valid.

It is in fact the general way to deal with qualifying what is "near" within a radius.

Also be aware of the "distance" according to how you have the coordinates stored. As legacy coordinate pairs the distances will be in radians which you will probably need to do the math to convert to kilometers or miles.

If using GeoJSON, then the distances are always considered in meters, as the standard format.

All the math notes are in the documentation.

> **N.B** Read the [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) documentation carefully. Options like `"spherical"` are required for `"2dsphere"` indexes, such as you should have for real world coordinates. Also `"limit"` may need to be applied to increase past the default 100 document result, for further trimming.

---

As the comments mention spring mongo, then here is basically the same thing done for that:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    new AggregationOperation() {
      @Override
      public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new BasicDBObject("$geoNear",
          new BasicDBObject(
            "near", new BasicDBObject(
              "type","Point")
              .append("coordinates", Arrays.asList(20,30))
            )
            .append("spherical",true)
            .append("distanceField","distance")
          );
        }
    },
    new AggregationOperation() {
      @Override
      public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new BasicDBObject("$redact",
          new BasicDBObject(
            "$cond", Arrays.asList(
               new BasicDBObject("$lte", Arrays.asList("$distance", "$travelDistance")),
               "$$KEEP",
               "$$PRUNE"
             )
          )
       );
     }
    }
);
```

Comment: It works, thank you. But I have another problem now, as I'm using Spring Data Mongodb framework, this still doesn't support $redact https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-931 :(

Comment: @LiLou_ It may not have a "helper" method, but you can always implement your own pipeline stage as an abstract using DBObject input. Several answers on this site about that. I know since I've written a few of them.

Comment: @LiLou_ Added the Spring Data Mongo translation of that and included the tag on the question. As you can see, adding custom pipeline stages and statements is fairly simple.

Comment: this aggregation would'n work with `$near` ? `$geoNear` is needed?

Comment: @LiLou_ `$geoNear` is the "aggregation" version of `$near`. You **need aggregation** and the `$geoNear` to return the "distance" to compare. You are not loosing anything. If you still do not understand then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Ok. I'm asking because `$geoNear` requieres `2dsphere` index although I don't need it, a `2d` index (`$near`) would be enough for me. Thanks again

Comment: @LiLou_ Please read the documentation as well as the words in the answer. If it's just a `2d` index then you don't need to include `spherical`, just leave it out of the pipeline options.