# Mongoose query returns wrong results when using $geoNear aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose query:

```
User.aggregate([
      {
        $geoNear: {
          near: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 1 , 1 ]},
          distanceField: 'dis',
          maxDistance: '$comRange' * 1000,
          spherical: true
        }
      },
      {
        $match: {isVolunteer: true, 'devices.enabled': true, }
      },
      {
        $group: { _id: '$devices.deviceID'.replace(/"/g, '')}
      }
    ],
    (err, locations) => {
      console.log('locations',JSON.stringify(locations, null, 4))
    }
  );
```

I have another field in document that contains the coords of the user:

```
volAddressCoords    : {type: Object, properties: {type: {type: String, enum: 'Point', default: 'Point'}, coordinates: {type: [Number], default: [0, 0]}, index: '2dsphere'}},
comRange            : {type: Number, min: 1, max: 20},
devices             : {type: Array}
```

devices is created when receiving a POST request in a different route:

```
let device = {
      enabled: true,
      deviceID : req.body.deviceId
    };
```

no matter what coordinate values (close or far away from comRange) I put on

`near: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 1 , 1 ]}`

it will always return this:

```
locations [
  {
    "_id": [
        "\"e_Fhn7sWzXE:APA91bGb5xpw4o\"",
        "\"eI2K-6iUvVw:APA91bGrdwh29H\""
           ]
  }
]
```

What am I missing here? When coordinates are far then there should be a blank array and when coordinates are inside `comRange` then it should populate the array.

Is there a better way to improve this query other than fixing it?

Comment: What you are missing is this `'$comRange' * 1000` where you are attempting to use the value existing in a document to supply `"maxDistance"`. You cannot do that there since this property does not examine existing documents. There is actually a completely different approach to restricting the distance relative to a document field than what your are attempting to implement.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for the comment, can you briefly explain the different approach that you suggest?

Comment: Well you have been linked to an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694847/geospatial-near-within-current-document-field-value) that does just that. Perhaps you should be looking at it and understanding the principles already explained.