# Spring Data MongoDB Aggregate with many fields in _id

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to make an aggregate with Spring Data MongoDB and I don't know how to make this group stage :

```
$group: {
                    _id: {
                        field1: "$field1",
                        field2: "2017-06-21",
                        field3: "$field3"
                    },

                    ...
                }
```

I don't know how to put the constant date into the second field of the _id

For the moment i do this :

```
groupOperation = group("field1","field3")
```

But i'm not sure that it make a group stage on the value of fields and i don't no how put a new field into _id.

I don't find good doc about the operation of different stage of an aggregate in Spring data MongoDB

If someone has an idea I'm interested

Thank you in advance

Comment: Still not supported AFAIK. Have not looked at the latest RC. Instead use `new AggregationOperation()` and write the entire `$group` using `BasicDBObject` classes. Or indeed with `Document` in the latest RC I believe. You might get some more feedback than that from one of the maintainers, but AFAIK it's still the only way to do it.

Comment: Sorry but  I don't see how this solves the problem, do you have an example ?

Comment: Sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694847/geospatial-near-within-current-document-field-value/44695584#44695584 shows defining a pipeline stage using `new AggregationOperation()`. Just one of many examples that can be found here.

Answer (score 2):

```
Fields fields = Fields.fields("field1", "field2", "field3");
GroupOperation groupOp = Aggregation.group(fields);
```

This will make group block

```
$group: {
        _id: {
            field1: "$field1",
            field2: "$field2",
            field3: "$field3"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using multiple fields on `group` and `count` the values.

```
Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.group("category", "status").count().as("Categoury_Status_Count"));

AggregationResults<String> aggregateResult = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregate, "category", String.class);

System.out.println(aggregateResult.getMappedResults());
```

**My Sample Data:-**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "category" : "cafe",
    "status" : "A"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "category" : "cafe",
    "status" : "B"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "category" : "cafe1",
    "status" : "A"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "category" : "cafe1",
    "status" : "B"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "category" : "cafe1",
    "status" : "B"
}
```

**Output:-**

```
[{ "category" : "cafe1" , "status" : "A" , "Categoury_Status_Count" : 1}, { "category" : "cafe" , "status" : "B" , "Categoury_Status_Count" : 1}, { "category" : "cafe1" , "status" : "B" , "Categoury_Status_Count" : 2}, { "category" : "cafe" , "status" : "A" , "Categoury_Status_Count" : 1}]
```

**To get the _id in the output:-**

You can add the _id to the set.

```
Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.group("category", "status").count().as("Categoury_Status_Count").addToSet("_id").as("ids"));
```

**Output:-**

```
[{ "category" : "cafe1" , "status" : "A" , "Categoury_Status_Count" : 1 , "ids" : [ 3.0]}, { "category" : "cafe" , "status" : "B" , "Categoury_Status_Count" : 1 , "ids" : [ 2.0]}, { "category" : "cafe1" , "status" : "B" , "Categoury_Status_Count" : 2 , "ids" : [ 5.0 , 4.0]}, { "category" : "cafe" , "status" : "A" , "Categoury_Status_Count" : 1 , "ids" : [ 1.0]}]
```

Comment: Thanks but in your example you lose the _id.
My Output should be look like this : 
`{_id : {"field1" : "...", "field2" : "....", "field3" : "..."}}`

Comment: added ids to output. As it can be multiple values, you need to add it to set.

Comment: Here, you add a new ids field, me, like a group stage in javascript on MongoBooster, what i would like it's that the group stage create automatically the field "_id" because this field it's like an index so it's important for perf