# MongoDB find documents using geo query depending on fields inside document

Tags: mongodb, geojson

The following is an example of a MongoDB document:

```
{
  radius: 5000,
  location: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [60.1241, 12.12454351] // [long, lat]
  }
}
```

Now I want to be able to query/find all documents for which a given point `p = [long, lat]` falls inside the radius given by the circle with center `location.coordinates` and radius `radius`.

The best I came up with is this

```
find({
  "location": {
    $geoWithin: {
      $centerSphere: [p, 5000],
    },
  },
});
```

but I do not know how to get the radius to not be hardcoded but be from the document field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question and created a working solution to my problem from that. ([Geospatial $near within current document field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694847/geospatial-near-within-current-document-field-value))

You have to add an index of 2dsphere first. (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/)

Then use the following aggregation:

```
aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [60.1241, 12.12454351],
      },
      distanceField: "distance",
      maxDistance: 40000, // optional (can be set if you know the max radius)
    },
  },
  {
    $redact: {
      $cond: {
        if: { $lte: ["$distance", "$radius"] },
        then: "$$KEEP",
        else: "$$PRUNE",
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

You first calculate and add a new field `distance`. Then you only keep the documents that have a distance lte the radius.